# Finding Microsoft++ multiple version and duplicates, is all really required?

Tags: windows, windows-10

While looking for ways to speed up my Windows 10 system, I discovered multiple versions of `Microsoft Visual C++` have been installed. I thought my system would be faster considering that I have a 8GB RAM installed, but my system seems to be very slow.

Can any one help me to understand if I need to keep all of these installed?
If I do not need all of these installed, can anyone help me to remove unwanted service files from this list?

[image]

Comment: Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable does not use system memory.  What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installed applications have little impact on their own on system speed.

These are frameworks that support software running on your system. Visual C++ packages are not installed by themselves but by software that requires them. You should not uninstall these unless you know which product requires them and have removed that software.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Visual C++ is a IDE used to create Windows applications in the C, C++ CLI programming languages. It was originally a standalone product, but is now included as part of Visual Studio. This runtime environment let's applications access many shared dynamic link libraries so it is very useful.

Some are included with Windows itself upon installation, Any additional versions of the Visual C++ Redistributable you see on your system were installed along with some program that required it. If a program is written in Visual C++ 2008 it would come with vcredist 2008. You may see more in 64 bit computers because there maybe both 32 and 64 bit editions, where 33 bit computers only have 32 bit editions.

Usually you should not uninstall them, as they are required by many programs, and uninstalling them may stop them working. It usually should take less than 400 MB of disk space (at least on my computer) and it is reasonable.

And It's almost impossible to tell which app depends on which vcredist unless you monitor every program installation for file changes.

So rather not focusing on important visual c++ installations, I would rather recommend you to remove unwanted apps and bloatware from  your computer.